# Get string content from string pointer C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers

so I'm working on a project that I have to read contents from a file and then analyze them. But I'm having a problem with getting the string out of a pointer that contains the address to what I need.

```
string lePapel(vector<char> vec){
    string *str, s;
    int i, j = 0;
    vector<char> aux;
    aux.resize(6);
    for (i = 57; i <= 62; i++){
        aux[j] = vec[i];
        j++;
       }
    str = new string[aux.size()];
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){ str[i] = aux[i]; }
return s;
}
```

So, the file contains in the array positions from 57 to 62 the word: `ABCB4`, but when returning the string s my output is `A` only as expected because of the pointer.

The thing is that I have been trying to find a solution and storing the whole content from `vec[57]` to `vec[64]` into the string s and returning it, and the closest that I got to returning anything plausible was using a pointer.

---

So, now to my question, how can I iterate the `*str` pointer and copy the whole content to s and return it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `string` a `std::string`?

Comment: Try `s.push_back(aux[i])` in your for loop

Comment: `return std::string(&vec[57], 62-57);`

Comment: Yes. string is a std::string. I'm using namespace std. As I was going to reply to someone who replied before who pointed out that I was returning s instead of str: Oh geez, I didn't pay attention. I have s = *str; before returning s. I copy & pasted without noticing. Apologies for that. Returning s after that gives me no errors, but I have no clue on how to iterate it and get the whole content I want, instead of just "A". Then again, returning *str does literally the same, and gets me to the same problem, not knowing how to iterate it.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks awesomeyi. That worked perfectly. I'm surprised I didn't think of that earlier. Kinda embarassed right now. Thanks again mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to not use pointers on string in your case. The following code is probably what you want :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string lePapel(vector<char> vec){
    int j = 0;
    vector<char> aux;
    aux.resize(6);
    for (int i = 57; i <= 62; i++){
        aux[j] = vec[j];
        j++;
    }
    string str;
    str.reserve(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){ str.push_back(aux[i]); }

    return str;
}

int main() {
    char x[5] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', '4'};
    vector<char> vec(x, x + 5);
    string s = lePapel(vec);
    cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Tested here : [Tested code](http://ideone.com/H66sXF)

About reserving space to your vector : [c++ vector::reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/)
Same for strings : [reserve for strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/reserve/)

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic array of `string` objects and the whole `aux` vector seem completely needless here (unless there's some other purpose for them in your code). Additionally, `str` is currently causing a memory leak because you never `delete` it when you're finished.

A much simpler approach is just to append the characters one-at-a-time to the `s` string object (assuming it's a `std::string`):

```
string lePapel(vector<char> vec) {
    string s;
    for (int i = 57; i <= 62; i++) {
        s += vec[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

There are various ways to make the code even shorter (and more efficient) than that though, if you really want to.

EDIT: If you still need/want to iterate your dynamic array and concatenate the contents into `s`, here's how you could do it:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) s += str[i];
delete [] str; //<-- very important!
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter. And yes, you are pretty much right about the point of these. That was just one messy way that **almost** got me a decent result. I got to use push_back as awesomeyi suggested up above and that worked fine. I will clean up the code and maybe mix up with your solution!

Comment: Just read your edited part. Thanks for explaining how to do that properly. I'm probably going to need that later on, and appreciated the reminder, I really did forget to delete the dynamic array

Comment: I suggest to use `s.reserve(6);` if you want to use `push_back` on `s`.

Comment: Is there any particular different between reserving and resizing the array in this case?

Comment: In theory, resize would probably be marginally faster than reserve for something like this, since you know the desired size in advance. You just need to use `s[i] = ...` instead of `s += ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you don't want a `string *` you want a `char *`. What you created is a `string` array. String objects *contain* a pointer to the `char *` data you are trying to capture. Also, the `sizeof(std::string)` (8 bytes in size) is a lot bigger than `sizeof(char)` (1 byte in size) the second character you store is 8 bytes away from the first character instead of being adjacent.

There are a lot of other C++ style and safety concerns, but I'll stick with the question. ;)

Comment: I suppose you were going to mention the unecessary variables and the memory leak caused by not deleting the *str, is that correct?

Comment: ... and j is never read, and vector gives you a constructor to allocate a size, and... there is a lot there.